# Создание эффекта увеличения параллакса с маской SVG Image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, анимация

Пытаюсь воссоздать эффект, найденный внизу [этой страницы](https://www.reformcollective.com/), где слова «REFORM CO» увеличивают масштаб, чтобы показать фоновое изображение с заголовком.

Попытался создать этот эффект сам, используя `skrollr.js`, но зашёл в тупик. В идеале я бы хотел, чтобы SVG был меньше и центрирован в маске, чтобы видео оставалось фиксированным до тех пор, пока маска не исчезнет, как в примере с REFORM CO.

Вот мой HTML и [ссылка на мою попытку](https://jsfiddle.net/uex526qs/1/):

```html
<body>

<div class="knockout">

  <svg x="50%" y="100%" class="knockout-text-container"  height="100%" data-0="opacity:1;transform: scale(1);" data-50p="opacity:0;font-size: 10em;transform: scale(10);">

    <rect class="knockout-text-bg" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="1" mask="url(#knockout-text)"/>

    <mask id="knockout-text">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" x="0" y="0"  />

      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 97.73 97.73"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#000;}</style></defs><title>shape2</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Content"><path class="cls-1" d="M48.86,97.73A7.72,7.72,0,0,1,41.15,90V7.72a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,15.43,0V90A7.72,7.72,0,0,1,48.86,97.73Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M90,56.58H7.72a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,0-15.43H90a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,0,15.43Z"/></g></g></svg>


    </mask>

  </svg>

</div>


<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


</body>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60215483/7394871

Answer (score 4):

> [Перевод ответа @Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60251068/7394871) на вопрос EnSO: [Recreating a
>   parallax zoom effect with SVG Image mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60215483/7394871)

1. Вы можете заставить элемент оставаться фиксированным относительно окна браузера, используя `position: fixed`
2. Чтобы масштабировать маску относительно элемента, к которому она применяется, используйте:

`<mask maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">`

Затем используйте координаты в диапазоне 0..1. Вот почему мои значения `scale()` такие маленькие. Ваша форма примерно `100x100`, поэтому мне нужно было прибавить еще `0,01`, чтобы уменьшить их до диапазона `0,1`.

Остальная часть вашего примера была более или менее правильной

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = skrollr.init();
  constants: {
    //заполните поле на «duration» 150% для viewport (пауза на 150%
    //настройка для короткой/длинной паузы
    knockout: '150p'
  }
})
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1500px;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
      <mask id="knockout" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <g fill="black"
           data-0="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.0015) translate(-49px,-49px);"
           data-50p="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.04) translate(-49px,-49px);">
          <path d="M48.86,97.73A7.72,7.72,0,0,1,41.15,90V7.72a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,15.43,0V90A7.72,7.72,0,0,1,48.86,97.73Z"/>
          <path class="cls-1" d="M90,56.58H7.72a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,0-15.43H90a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,0,15.43Z"/>
        </g>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" mask="url(#knockout)"/>
  </svg>

</div>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60251068/7394871): @Paul LeBeau

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить интересные варианты, если изменять `path` для маски и атрибуты масштабирования и анимации.

Наверное можно обдумать возможность использование в веб дизайне видео кнопок, которые получаются при симбиозе видео и маски.

**Вертикальный скроллинг**

Смотрите в полно экранном режиме

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1500px;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<p class="txt" style="font-size:24px; color:dodgerblue; text-align:center"> Scroll </p> 
<div class="container">

  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/956577/screenshots/9748924/media/52cecfa762404221c0c909edbbbccf78.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
      <mask id="knockout" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <g fill="black"
           data-0="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.0003) translate(-49px,-49px);"
           data-250p="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.04) translate(-49px,-49px);">
          <path d="M48.86,97.73A7.72,7.72,0,0,1,41.15,90V7.72a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,15.43,0V90A7.72,7.72,0,0,1,48.86,97.73Z"/>
         
        </g>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" mask="url(#knockout)"/>
  </svg>

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = skrollr.init();
  constants: {
    
    knockout: '250p'
  }
})
</script>
```

**Горизонтальный скроллинг**

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1500px;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<p class="txt" style="font-size:24px; color:dodgerblue; text-align:center"> Scroll </p> 
<div class="container">

  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/956577/screenshots/7123415/media/1d16d2a46974b1f26e23715be6760e55.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
      <mask id="knockout" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <g fill="black"
           data-0="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.0001) translate(-49px,-49px);"
           data-250p="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.04) translate(-49px,-49px);">
          
          <path class="cls-1" d="M90,56.58H7.72a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,0-15.43H90a7.72,7.72,0,1,1,0,15.43Z"/>
        </g>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" mask="url(#knockout)"/>
  </svg>

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = skrollr.init();
  constants: {
   
    knockout: '250p'
  }
})
</script>
```

**Скроллинг круглой маски**

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1500px;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.30/skrollr.min.js"></script>
 <p class="txt" style="font-size:36px; color:dodgerblue; text-align:center"> Scroll </p> 
<div class="container">

  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
    <source src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/956577/screenshots/7088448/media/6fc78c4981da9b0865c34877e5c10e06.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
    <defs>
      <mask id="knockout" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="white"/>
        <g fill="black"
           data-0="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.0015) translate(-50px,-50px);"
           data-250p="transform: translate(0.5px,0.5px) scale(0.5) translate(-50px,-50px);">
          <path d="m 55.280169,50.113018 a 5.393187,6.2920518 0 0 1 -5.393187,6.292052 5.393187,6.2920518 0 0 1 -5.393187,-6.292052 5.393187,6.2920518 0 0 1 5.393187,-6.292052 5.393187,6.2920518 0 0 1 5.393187,6.292052 z"/>
          
        </g>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white" mask="url(#knockout)"/>
  </svg>

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = skrollr.init();
  constants: {
    //заполните поле на «duration» 150% для viewport (пауза на 150%
    //настройка для короткой/длинной паузы
    knockout: '250p'
  }
})
</script>
```